# Migration to Hibernate 6

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to migration my project to Hibernante 6 but I face some problems...

1. "type" attribute of @Type annotation is not recognized : @Type(type
   = "yes_no")
2. Problem to instanciate entityManagerFactory :

   ```
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(**HibernatePersistenceProvider.class**);
   ```

HibernatePersistenceProvider implements jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider instead of javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider

Have you any idea please ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Hibernate 6.x with Spring Boot 2.7.x not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73257636/using-hibernate-6-x-with-spring-boot-2-7-x-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

For Hibernate 6 you'll need a 3.x release of Spring Data JPA.
The latest Spring Data JPA release is 3.0.0 M4

Even with that Hibernate 6 support is flaky since Hibernate broke a lot of stuff both internally and for users as Spring Data JPA.

I'd recommend waiting until 3.0.0 GA.

Answer (score 0):

For issue #1, as stated in the [Hibernate 6.0 migration guide here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.0/migration-guide.adoc#boolean-converters),

Hibernate < 6.0:

```
@Type(type="yes_no")
boolean isActive;
```

Hibernate >= 6.0:

```
@Convert(converter=YesNoConverter.class)
boolean isActive;
```